# why fabric release 1.1.0 could not make?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

From fabric [makefile](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/v1.1.0/Makefile) ,I wanna compile the orderer and peer ,It throws the error

```
friendsdeMacBook-Pro:fabric friends$ make orderer
make: *** No rule to make target `build/bin/orderer', needed by `orderer'.  Stop.
friendsdeMacBook-Pro:fabric friends$
```

I changed the official makefile a little, my changed Makefile file:
 [changed Makefile](https://github.com/friends110110/temp/blob/master/Makefile)

Answer (score 0):

After taking a git clone of https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric check which branch or tag you are in before invoking make commands.

```
$ git clone of https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric

$ git checkout v1.1.0

$ make release
```